# Add three dot floating numbers in shell

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, arithmetic

I am trying to append 5.34.03 number to 5.34.04 by using the following command

```
$ awk '{print 5.34.03 + 0.0.1}'
5.340.030.1
```

Expected output

```
5.34.13
```

I tried with many methods, eg. **let**, but it didn't work.

Comment: If it works like floats, shouldn't the result be 5.34.13?

Comment: @choroba ah, you're right. thanks, will modify the question.

Comment: Appending `5.34.03` to `5.34.04` would surely result in `5.34.045.34.03`? Why do you call these strings "numbers"?.  No numbers, not even floating point numbers, have multiple decimal dots in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your minor version and patch version numbers should be 2 characters, you can use this awk script:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN { FS = "[ .]"; OFS = "." }

function tonum(s) {
  if( length(s) < 2 )
    s *= 10
  return s
}

function tover(n) {
  if( n < 10 )
    n = "0" n
  return n
}

{
  print $1 + $4, tover( tonum($2) + tonum($5) ), tover( tonum($3) + tonum($6) )
}
```

Run it like this:

```
echo 5.34.03 0.0.1 | awk -f parse.awk
```

Output:

```
5.34.13
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can split each version string using IFS and populate an array with its numbers. Then use parameter expansion to get lengths of the numbers and use `printf` to format the resulting numbers:

```
#! /bin/bash
v=5.34.03
a=0.0.1

IFS=.
v=($v)
a=($a)

shopt -s extglob
for ((i=0; i<${#v[@]}; i++)) ; do
    v[i]=${v[i]%%+(0)}
    a[i]=${a[i]%%+(0)}
    v_length=${#v[i]}
    a_length=${#a[i]}
    v[i]=${v[i]##+(0)}
    a[i]=${a[i]##+(0)}
    if (( v_length < a_length )) ; then
        length=$a_length
        (( v[i] *= 10 ** (a_length - v_length) ))
    else
        length=$v_length
        (( a[i] *= 10 ** (v_length - a_length) ))
    fi
    (( v[i] += a[i] ))
    v[i]=$(printf %0"$length"d ${v[i]})
done
IFS=.
echo "${v[*]}"

IFS=$' \t\n'
```

I needed to handle leading and trailing zeroes as numbers like 010 are treated as octal.

Comment: thanks. It works fine until 09 (e.g. 5.34.09), after that if I try to append 09 to 10, it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?